# Jsoup 'EscapeMode.getMap()' missing after update to version 1.10.1

Tags: java, jsoup

Just updated Jsoup from version 1.9.2 to version 1.10.1.
Now I have a compile error on the following line:

```
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode().getMap().put('\u200b', "#8203");
```

[EscapeMode](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.EscapeMode.html) is missing the `getMap()` method.

How can I manipulate the escape mode in the new version?

Comment: Are you using that in order to convert a character to a different character? Why not replace the character to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean with "to begin with"? Just use `String.replaceAll()`?

Comment: `String.replace()` (there is no need to use a regex for just a single particular character). Yes.